# Insert elements to the matrix using index

Tags: arrays, matlab

I would like to add the elements to the array using their index.

```
array_in = [1 5 6 8 9];
index = [2 4];
newElements = [25 67];
index = index + (0:length(index)-1);
```

expected output:

```
array_out = [1 25 5 6 67 8 9];
```

1.using for loop:

```
 tmp = array_in;

for idx = 1:length(index)
  array_out =  cat(2,tmp(1:index(idx)-1),newElements(idx),tmp(index(idx):end));
  tmp = array_out;
end
```

2.The code for Calling a Function Using Its Handle:

```
fcn_Insert = @(a, x, n) cat(2,  x(1:n-1), a, x(n:end));
array_out = fcn_Insert(newElements,array_in,index)
```

The above code.2 (function) is not working? can any one suggest the solution. Are there any other better solutions?

Comment: The way you have done it is rigth, but in your function, you only allow 1 index as an input. therefore if you input more than once the behaviour will not be what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a [`sort`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html)-based approach:

```
array_out = [array_in newElements];             %// append new to old
[~, ind] = sort([1:numel(array_in) index-.5]);  %// determine new order needed
array_out = array_out(ind);                     %// apply that order
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this before Luis's answer was accepted. It ran over twice as fast, if people are interested.

```
function array_out = Insert(array_in, index, values)
    array_out = zeros(length(array_in)+length(index), 1);

    oldIndex = ~ismember(1:length(array_out), index);

    array_out(index) = values;
    array_out(oldIndex) = array_in;
end
```